# Lua, Love2d, two games with the same class name in different folders

Tags: file, lua, 2d-games, love2d

I'm new to Lua and Love2D, I did 2-3 simple games and I wanted to put them together. I did a window where you choose which game you want to play. It succeed; with a little problem. Two of my games use a ball. So both have a Ball.lua File. I use the require function to load the Ball file in each of my games. It works at first, I can play Game1, go back and play Game2 without any problem. But if I go back and want to play the Game1 again. His ball.lua File will not be required since require only load once. Then there will have an error since my game1 is trying to use my Game2's ball Class.

I wanted to know which solution would be best :

1. Just rename the files. (I would like to avoid it, feels hardcoding to me)
2. Use doFile. (I never used it, I don't even know if it would work)
3. Require the two Ball's Classes in my Main menu and pass it by parameter when loading each game (Don't know if it would work too)

If you want to see my code for more explanation, here's the link : https://github.com/cbelangerstpierre/Games/tree/main/Games

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Two files with the same name are no problem, and I get no error regarding this issue either when executing your code. It crashes because of something different. Seems like you did not clean up properly before the second run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, `require` will only execute each file once. However it will also save the return value of the file so you can `require` the file as many times as you want and still get the same value.

In your `Ball.lua` files, make your `Ball` declarations local:

```
local Ball = Class{}
```

Then at the bottom of those files add:

```
return Ball
```

Then, change your `main.lua` files to store to the global `Ball` variable:

```
Ball = require "Atari-Breakout.Ball"
```

and

```
Ball = require("Switching-Ball.Ball")
```

Ideally, it's recommended to make all of your variables local and return tables from the files that you need to `require`.

Comment: Ohhh nice it worked ! Thanks a lot, 
You say that you would use local variables instead. But I don't understand, would use local variables EVERYWHERE ? like when you say I do Ball = require, isn't it global ?

Comment: Yes, I wrote it that way to minimize changes to your code. Normally, you would put something like `local Ball = require "Atari-Breakout.Ball"` near the top of every file that uses the Ball class. Then each of those files would have its own local variable that references the same table that defines the class or library.